# Deletar Laravel6x - com SweetAlert2

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel-6, sweetalert2

Como sou iniciante utilizando o Laravel (versão 6x) estou com um problema para realizar um Delete, estou utilizando o SweetAlert para realizar a exclusão
segue o erro do console:

```
POST http://localhost:8000/Atividades/destroy/ 405 (Method Not Allowed)
```

View:

```
<button type="submit" id="deletar" onclick="return deletar({{$atividade->id}})"
class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" ><i class="fas fa-trash"></i></button>


    function deletar(id) {
    Swal.fire({
    title: 'Confirma e exclusão?',
    text: "esta ação é irreversivel..",
    icon: 'warning',
    showCancelButton: true,
    confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
    cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
    cancelButtonText: 'Cancelar',
    confirmButtonText: 'Sim, vou deletar!'
    }).then((result) => {
        if(result.value){
            $.ajax({
                url: `{{route ('atividade.destroy')}}/`,
                type:'POST',
                data: {
                        '_method': 'DELETE',
                        '_token': '{{csrf_token()}}',
                        'id': id

                    },
                success: function (response)  {
                        $('#example2').DataTable().ajax.reload();
                        swal({
                            type:'success',
                            title: 'Sucesso',
                            text: 'Atividade Deletada !!!'
                        });
                    }
            });
        }
    })
}
```

Controller

```
public function destroy($id)
{
    $model = Atividade::findOrFail($id);
    $model->delete();
}
```

Model

```
class Atividade extends Model
{
   protected $fillable = ['atividade'];
   protected $guarded = ['id', 'created_at', 'update_at'];
   protected $table = 'atividades';
}
```

Route

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth'], 'prefix' => 'Atividades'], function() 
{
Route::get('/', 'AtividadesController@index')->name('atividade.home');
Route::post('/store', 'AtividadesController@store')->name('atividade.store');
Route::post('/destroy', 'AtividadesController@destroy')->name('atividade.destroy');
});
```

Comment: Tem certeza que o verbo `HTTP` utilizado por essa rota é `DELETE`? Porque esse erro acontece quando você tenta utilizar uma rota com um verbo `HTTP` diferente do que ela foi configurada.

Comment: Se a rota tiver configurada corretamente como `DELETE ` tenta alterar o `type` do seu ajax de `POST` para `DELETE `. Mas continue enviando o `'_method': 'DELETE'` no seu data.

Comment: DELETE http://localhost:8000/Atividades/destroy/ 405 (Method Not Allowed)

Comment: Amigo o seu arquivo de rotas está mostrando que está configurado como `POST` e não delete. Altere para `Route::delete('/destroy', 'AtividadesController@destroy')->name('atividade.destroy');`

Comment: DELETE http://localhost:8000/Atividades/destroy/ 500 (Internal Server Error) agora é so descobrir o erro interno.
Muitoobg

Comment: Olha o arquivo de log.

Comment: como faço isso?

Comment: `storage/logs/laravel.log`

Comment: pode me ajudar?
[2020-02-28 18:24:24] local.ERROR: Too few arguments to function App\Http\Controllers\AtividadesController::destroy(), 0 passed and exactly 1 expected {"userId":1,"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalThrowableError(code: 0): Too few arguments to function App\\Http\\Controllers\\AtividadesController::destroy(), 0 passed and exactly 1 expected at C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\programacao\\app\\Http\\Controllers\\AtividadesController.php:54)
[stacktrace]

Comment: Sua rota precisa de um path param que é o ID de quem você vai remover. Então no seu ajax vc precisa informar a sua rota concatenando com o ID de quem vc quer remover
e não passar ele pelo body do request, ou você pode remover o parâmetro do seu método destroy e pegar o ID pelo body do request.

Comment: Acho que isso deve funcionar: ```url: `{{route ('atividade.destroy')}}/` + id,```

Comment: Tem mais alguns detalhes que estão errados no seu arquivo de rota, vou criar uma resposta corrigindo tudo.

Comment: Kayo eu agradeço imensamente sua ajuda, fiz a alteração que vc mencionou e gerou o erro DELETE http://localhost:8000/Atividades/destroy/1 404 (Not Found)
e aproveito para agradecer novamente com sua resposta com a correção

Comment: Você atualizou seu arquivo de rota?

Comment: atualizei a rota e gerou o erro
Missing required parameters for [Route: atividade.destroy] [URI: Atividades/destroy/{id}]. (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\programacao\resources\views\atividades\index.blade.php)

Comment: Tenta isso no seu AJAX: ```url: `{{route ('atividade.destroy', [$atividade->id])}}`,``` ou ```url: `{{route ('atividade.destroy', ['id' => $atividade->id])}}`,```

Comment: depois que eu alterei a rota o erro permanece mesmo alterando a rota no ajax.

Missing required parameters for [Route: atividade.destroy] [URI: Atividades/destroy/{id}]. (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\programacao\resources\views\atividades\index.blade.php)

Answer (score 0):

#### Controller

```
public function destroy($id)
{
    $model = Atividade::findOrFail($id);
    $model->delete();
}
```

#### Route

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth'], 'prefix' => 'Atividades'], function() 
{
    Route::delete('/destroy/{id}', 'AtividadesController@destroy')->name('atividade.destroy');
});
```

#### View

```
<button type="submit" id="deletar" onclick="return deletar({{$atividade->id}})"
class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" ><i class="fas fa-trash"></i></button>
    function deletar(id) {
    Swal.fire({
    title: 'Confirma e exclusão?',
    text: "esta ação é irreversivel..",
    icon: 'warning',
    showCancelButton: true,
    confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
    cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
    cancelButtonText: 'Cancelar',
    confirmButtonText: 'Sim, vou deletar!'
    }).then((result) => {
        if(result.value){
            $.ajax({
                // Não me recordo bem mas acho que a função "route" recebe um segundo parâmetro que é um array com os parâmetros da sua rota, você pode confirmar isso na documentação.
                url: `{{route ('atividade.destroy')}}/` + `{{ $atividade->id }}`,
                type:'POST',
                data: {
                        '_method': 'DELETE',
                        '_token': '{{csrf_token()}}',
                        'id': id

                    },
                success: function (response)  {
                        $('#example2').DataTable().ajax.reload();
                        swal({
                            type:'success',
                            title: 'Sucesso',
                            text: 'Atividade Deletada !!!'
                        });
                    }
            });
        }
    })
}
```